# Adding a new Entity Framework shows warning and no wizard is displayed

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2017

Every time I want to add an Entity Data Model using "EF 6.x DbContext Generator" to my VB.Net project, this warning appears instead of "Entity Data Model Wizard":

> Running this text template can potentially harm your computer.Do not run it , if u obtained it from an untrusted source
>
> Click OK to run the template
>
> Click Cancel to stop the process

And when I click OK no wizard is showing. just two .tt file are added to the project. These .tt files are opened as text files.

I tried this with several new projects and this error happens everytime.

I have Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017. Version 15.7.6

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of adding a new Entity Framework Model using the "Entity Data Model Wizard" is selecting **ADO.NET Entity Data Model** in the "Add New Item" window instead of **EF 6.x DbContext Generator**.

But that warning will still show sometimes.

Comment: To clear the warning you can go to Tools -> Options -> Text Templating and set "Show Security Message" to "False", but this is dangerous.

Answer (score -1):

go to path:
Tools > Options-> Text Templating ->Show Security Message set  False